# State machine transitions rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state, state-machine

I have state transitions as follows:

```
  [A,B] => C
  [B,C] => A
```

I am using before_transition, after_transition methods as follows:

```
  before_transition :to => C do
  end
```

But now I got a situation to use above method as follows

```
  before_transition :from=> A, :to => C do
  end
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You mean you want to apply the before transition only for `A=>C` not for `B=>C`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably like this

```
before_transition :A => :B, :do => :action
... ... ...
def action
    #do your stuffs here.
end
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use

```
before_transition :to => 'canceled', :from => 'new_order', :do => [:cancel_account_movement]

def cancel_account_movement
   #blablabla
end
```